# Android App crashes if i lock the screen and unlock again

Tags: android, crash, lockscreen

I have a main menu activity. It has 8 different options. On tapping on any of these option a web service is called respectively. The data is fetched and it is shown in a table layout. Everything is fine until I lock the phone. In `Logcat` I can see that the same web service is called again. When I unlock the phone the async is displayed and the data is fetched again. Sometimes all goes fine although the app crashes a lot.

I want that when on locking and unlocking the phone the web service is not called and the page is shown as it is.